# Window resize bug on Android

Tags: android, jquery

On android triggered event window resize when you click on the input text or search. From there it take if resizing the window does not occur. I shoveled a lot of sources, how to fix I do not know.
Accordingly, I have written that when the browser is resized remove attributes eventually INPUT text disappears
https://youtu.be/2pAL221qgwc
https://youtu.be/W4M4c4UzMfc

Comment: `I have written that when the browser is resized remove attributes`??? Can you share MCVE?

Comment: Sorry! 
I have not written there.1) In the event window resize removes attributes style
2) When I click on the Android to input text, then it disappears, because he has lost the attributes of style.

Comment: Why the  Window Resize event occurs when click on input text is not understand?.

Comment: What you don't understand is that you have to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue... And is it your own window resize event handler or what???

Comment: Minimalistic sample replicating your issue I pointed out below in the answers, now I will duplicate here. Yes. this is my own window resize event handler.

Comment: You have to edit question itself, not posting relevant info as answer(s). Now the logic you are doing in window resize has no meaning as i can see it. Why do you want to remove style attribute on window resize without any check regrading window width/height? You would anyway have better to use CSS media queries, google it

Comment: I get message "too long by 94 characters" if insert code here. Look below in the responses, please

Comment: I was not talking about posting code in comment BUT edit your question and post it there...

Comment: You mean @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {} ? This may be the solution! now I will try, thanks.

Comment: >I was not talking about posting code in comment BUT edit your question and post it there... Sorry! I understand. And why all the same the Android may conflict in the event Window Resize?

Comment: That's an OS/browser depending feature i guess, displaying virtual keyboard fires the resize event, just like when scrolling, removing the address bar could

Comment: AAA for sure! Thank you very much.But this is the  General Bug why the developers did not think the official fix to be able to use the Windows Resize event.) Or I dont found this  on the Internet...

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, more like a specific behaviour. Now your logic inside resize event was quite wrong because again, you weren't checking for any specific condition as window width or height or both.

Comment: How to remove the style attribute from the media? If you override, then the script does not work.

Comment: And you can specify the event window size only when the Width of browser change?

Comment: ...............help me! Please!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('nav>#main-menu').click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $('.nav-menu ul ').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.nav-menu ul' ).slideDown();

    }
});

//search-toggle 
$('.icon-b').click(function() {
    //$( "#search-bl" ).slideToggle( "500");
    $( "#search-bl" ).toggle( "slide",{ direction: "right" });

});

$(window).resize(function() {
            $('.nav-menu ul').removeAttr('style');
            $('#search-bl').removeAttr('style');
            $('nav>#main-menu').removeClass('active');

                 });
```

});

I forgot to add.